# how to pass data from View to as an object Controller using ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a search ajax request like this:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: { FirstName: firstname, LastName: lastname},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'GetPeople',
        dataType: 'json',

      }
    });
```

In GetPeole action  I can get my parameter (FirstName,LastName)

```
public virtual JsonResult GetPeople(string FirstName,string LastName)
        {
          ....
        }
```

If i change my ajax request like

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: { FirstName: firstname, LastName: lastname,Age=age},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'GetPeople',
        dataType: 'json',

      }
    });
```

I must change my GetPeople

```
 public virtual JsonResult GetPeople(string FirstName,string LastName,int Age)
        {
          ....
        }
```

I want get my searchparameters(FirstName,LastName,Age) as an object in Getpeople like this

```
public virtual JsonResult GetPeople(searchParam)
    {
        .....
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare a class for your parameter like so:

```
public class SearchFilters {
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

and use it in your controller like this:

```
public JsonResult GetPeople(SearchFilters filters) {
}
```

and in your ajax post you need to pass the data like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ FirstName: firstname, LastName: lastname,Age=age})
```